# PHLivePhoto Not Playing On UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, phlivephoto

I have created a `UICollectionView` that will display live photo's, the live photos are stored in an array and are working fine, except when i try to display them on the `UICollectionViewCell`'s. They just wont play.

Here's what i tried : Added a `UIView` and changed its class to `PHLivePhotoView`, i've also tried adding an `UIImageView` and changing it's class just in case. I tried playing the live photos programmatically with:
`cell.livePhotoView.startPlaybackWithStyle(PHLivePhotoViewPlaybackStyle.Full)`

Which didn't work. Tried checking if my preview image was on top of the PHLivePhotoView, it wasn't the case.

If i take this route everything works fine

```
let livePhotoView = PHLivePhotoView(frame: self.previewImage.frame)
self.view.addSubview(livePhotoView)
livePhotoView.startPlaybackWithStyle(PHLivePhotoViewPlaybackStyle.Full)
```

The above works as expected.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? I don't know what i have overlooked.